# Replacing a character in Java Script by end line

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, browser, replace

In java script I have a string. I need to replace each '$' character in this string with an end line. I tried the following,

```
for(var i=0; i<textAreaText.length; i++)
{
if(textAreaText[i]=="$")
textAreaText=textAreaText.replaceAt(i,"\n")
}

document.getElementById("textArea").value=textAreaText;
```

function replaceAt:

```
   String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, chare) {
      return this.substr(0, index) + chare + this.substr(index+chare.length);
   }
```

It worked on Google Chrome but not on Internet Explorer. On Internet Explorer, the '$' is replaced by a space. When I copy paste this space to a notepad, it turns out that it is actually an end line. I have no idea what Internet Explorer is thinking, but I need a cross browser solution. Can you help? Thanks.

Note: I am using Java Server Pages, and this string was initially assigned in the java code, but later copied as a Java Script var.

Comment: is textAreaText an array?

Comment: There is no `replaceAt` method in Javascript. Is the first part of the code Java?

Comment: No the first part is still Java Script, but I define that function. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
var textAreaText = document.getElementById("textArea").value;
textAreaText = textAreaText.replace(/\$/g, "\n")
document.getElementById("textArea").value = textAreaText;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g4N3L/2

Comment: Although your code works on the Demo, it does not work in my case. Maybe because I am using JSP and the string with dollar signs come from a java string.